# Why am I able to access EC2 metadata endpoint from within a Docker container running in the EC2

Tags: aws, docker, container, escape

My understanding of containers is very basic and so is my understanding of AWS EC2. Recently while trying to debug a security issue, I came across a scenario where I was able to gain an RCE. Whether this RCE was in a container or on the EC2 is still not clear.  But one thing of interest was that through the RCE I was able to access the EC2 metadata endpoint at

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

Now I have a couple of conceptual questions here:

1. How come from within a container I am able to access the EC2
   metadata?
2. Does it mean that the EC2 can also be accessed from within the container (like a container escape of some sorts)?
3. I have access to the STS token, the access key id and the access key secret leaking through the metadata endpoint. How can I check the privileges of this token?

Comment: what is the purpose of your 1st and 2nd questions, since you don't know whether the RCE executed the command from the container or the hosting EC2 instance?

Comment: I am not sure whether it was executed from within the container or not. I am suspecting that it was from within the container though, because of some indications, like proc/1/cgroup shows some of the cgroups belonging to Docker. But since I was able to access the EC2 metadata, I am confused now. And hence all 3 of my questions. @Spyros

Comment: are you using a container orchestration platform (e.g. kubernetes) or plain docker images executing in EC2 instances?

Comment: why should you not be able to access this address from inside the container? what do you suppose would stop you from doing so?

Comment: @user253751 I think because from within the container I should be in a completely isolated environment than the host (the ec2), unless explicitly allowed otherwise. And my understanding is since the metadata is accessible from the ec2, which is isolated from the container, it should not be accessible from within the container.

Comment: @Spyros it’s a plain docker container. No Kubernetes

Comment: @qre0ct What do you think completely isolated means? You can still access the internet, right? And 169.254.169.254 is just an IP address.

Comment: @user253751 yeah, you're right! :thinking_face: 
More reading suggests 169.254.169.254 is a link local address. Pardon my limited understanding here again, but it seems that link local address would be accessible only within the local network segment. If that's right, the container & the host must both be on the same local network for the container to be able to access that 169.254.169.254. And consequently, does it mean that the container would also have access to the other EC2/containers on the same local network? (subject to any other network restrictions of course) :thinking_face:

Comment: @qre0ct It's just an address. Calling it link-local is a convention as an address in the 169.254 space is allocated by default by some operating systems if they detect no DHCP server and don't have a static address. This is called APIPA (automatic private IP addressing). However, that's nothing intrinsic to the address itself.

Comment: @user253751 makes sense. But even then, if it's just another address, like any other address it would be accessible within in the same network segment. No? And so, (repeating this part from my previous comment) the container & the host must both be on the same local network for the container to be able to access that 169.254.169.254. And consequently, does it mean that the container would also have access to the other EC2/containers on the same local network? (subject to any other network restrictions of course) :thinking_face:

Comment: @qre0ct I can access security.stackexchange.com even though I'm not on the same network segment. I am not sure how Docker sets up networking but I assume it wants your container to be able to access the Internet, so any requests to addresses that aren't special Docker addresses will just go out from the host.